# Image_tag generating extra data on show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, show

I have an image tag for a nested image with paperclip.

The image is well displayed but i have this just under :

[#<Picture id: 8, post_id: 7, created_at: "2015-12-23 18:37:33", updated_at: "2015-12-23 18:37:33", image_file_name: "Clichey3.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 93529, image_updated_at: "2015-12-23 18:37:33">]

[image: Bug]

here my show :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%= @post.pictures.each do |pic| %>
  <%= image_tag(pic.image.url(:medium)) %>
<% end %>
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Weird ?? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with this, you don't want the '=' on the loop.  I forget if it's a '-' or nothing.

```
<% @post.pictures.each do |pic| %>
  <%= image_tag(pic.image.url(:medium)) %>
<% end %>
```